# Youtube embedded iframe onReady and onStateChange events not firing in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have copied the Youtube embedded player demo code [Youtube embedded player demo code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) almost verbatim - the changes are inserting console.log so that I can see what is going on.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        console.log('onPlayerReady');
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
          console.log('onPlayerStateChange');
          if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This works as intended in Safari and Firefox, that is once the API loads the choosen video plays for six seconds and the console.log contains evidence that the events are firing.  However in Internet Explorer the events onReady and onStateChange do not fire.  The video will play if I manually click the play control in the player but I do not get the expected onStateChange events.

I checked the version of Flash on my machine and it is: 11.2.202.228 and the current available is 12.0.0.70.  If I disable Flash in IE (manage add ons) the player works as expected: plays for 6 seconds and events fire.

I did not update Flash because while that might fix the issue on my machine my audience will be limited to those only that can do the same and if I updated I would not be able to find out if the issue was resolved by other means.

I have also tried to manually create the iframe myself as mentioned in the above Youtube documentation, this worked as expected in Firefox and Safari but not in IE.

There is a [Youtube demo player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo)  this works perfectly in Firefox, the play, pause and stop controls via the API work and the events are clearly firing as the Events and Function Calls are written to the screen in the "Statistics" section.  In contrast when I look at this in IE the play, pause and stop controls via the API do nothing.  There is no output in the statistics section.  The only way to play and pause is to use the buttons on the player.  If I disable Flash then the player & API works perfectly.

If I try an iframe non API embed then the player works correctly, this leads me to believe that it is an issue arising from using the API.

I know some would say that all users should have the latest Flash, easier said than done.  Many schools, companies and libraries lock down the options section in IE so the user would be able to turn off Flash for my site.

I wonder is there some way of turning off Flash when using the API?

I have searched around Stackoverflow and elsewhere and while I have found similar issues I have not found any fixes.  [I did find a somewhat similar promising lead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078094/youtube-iframe-player-api-onstatechange-not-firing) but alas I had no joy.  [Also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206285/youtube-iframe-api-onready-onstatechange-not-firing-in-ie-8) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=2942) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5670&q=onready&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857686/youtube-iframe-events) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4706#c93).

I must point out that the issue is present when used on a local machine and on a website and even if I set the origin parameter.

I would appreciate suggestions and help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  This describes my situation beautifully.

Comment: Did you try to set the `html5` attribute in the source url? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845484/force-html5-youtube-video

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder is there some way of turning off Flash when using the API?

You could force the YouTube player to use its html5 player using the following option:

```
playerVars: {html5: 1}
```

Changing your code to:

```
// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
    playerVars: {
      html5: 1
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}
```